# How do I initialize a collection of a record set, when each property for a record set is in separate .txt file C#

Tags: c#, file-io, initialization, recordset

I apologize for a confusing title, that's the only way I knew to explain the situation I'm dealing in a title.

I have a record set which contains properties for sesmic activity data. To give an example, it contains fields like iris ID, longitude, latitude, magnitude and many others. I'm given separate .txt files for these fields which contain 600 entries of that particular data.

Now, what I have done so far is created another class which will be basically collection of the recordSet in a form of a list.

Where I have trouble is basically figuring out how to go about a method which will allow me to initialize the list of the record sets with data from files that are each separate.

This is how my method looks so far:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this manner...

```
public void iniSets(int dataSet)
{
  DirectoryInfo dataColumns = new DirectoryInfo(@"SesmicData\");//Assuming Test is your Folder
  FileInfo[] Files = dataColumns.GetFiles($"*{dataSet}.txt"); //Getting Text files
  foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
  {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
      string line;
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        if (file.Name.StartsWith("column_a"))
        {
          // parse column A data per data type and store where it needs to be stored
        }
        else if (file.Name.StartsWith("column_b"))
        {
          // parse column B data per data type and store where it needs to be stored
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```